# Updating JTable Cell with Date type

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jtable

i've followed some stackoverflow responses to this problem and every answer i found contributed a bit to solve the problem, however i'm still stuck.

I still can't update a table cell with the Date Type, i click the cell and edit it, but when i press Enter it won't update, it won't even let me leave the cell it just displays a red border around it. I would appreciate some insight, thank you.

getColumnClass method:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) throws IllegalStateException {
    String columnName;

    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }

    columnName = getColumnName(column);

    if(columnName.equals("id")) {
        return java.lang.Integer.class;
    }

    switch (table) {
        case 0:
            if (columnName.equals("dn") || columnName.equals("ade")) {
                return java.util.Date.class;                    
            } else {
               return java.lang.String.class;
            }
        default:
            try {
                String className = metaData.getColumnClassName(column + 1);
                return Class.forName(className);
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                return Object.class;
            }
    }
}
```

getValueAt method:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }

    try {
        resultSet.absolute(row + 1);
        return resultSet.getObject(column + 1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

setValueAt method:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    String columnName = getColumnName(columnIndex);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate;
    switch (table) {
        case 0:
            if (columnName.equals("dn") || columnName.equals("de")) {
                sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date) value).getTime());
                try {
                    resultSet.absolute(rowIndex + 1);
                    resultSet.updateDate(columnIndex + 1, sqlDate);
                    resultSet.updateRow();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    resultSet.absolute(rowIndex + 1);
                    resultSet.updateString(columnIndex + 1, (String) value);
                    resultSet.updateRow();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
    }
    this.fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red border around the cell indicates that the date format you entering is wrong. If you are using a default date editor then try entering a date with a simple format, ie: `DD/MM/YYYY`.

For example here is a red border for a `DD-MM-YYYY` format that cannot be parsed by `Date`:

[image]

A default editor that is used by `JTable` for date columns attempts to create `Date` object from the entered value. Either comply with the expected format or provide you own custom editor. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for some examples.

Comment: Entering the date in the DD/MM/YYYY format worked thank  you!, but i have a slight problem, the date in the table is displayed in this format: (ex: "29/Jan/1980") when i try to edit the cell it shows up as YYYY-MM-DD how can i keep the format consistent in those 2 views (DD/MM/YYYY)?

Comment: @user2382836 you can create custom editor. See the concept of editors and renderers in the mentioned tutorial.